# Does gluLookAt() have a limit on smallest argument size?

Tags: c++, opengl, glulookat

I have an OpenGL program which works when I call this:

`gluLookAt(0.1,0.1,0.1, 0,0,0, 0,0.1,0);`

... but not when I call this:

`gluLookAt(0.01,0.01,0.01, 0,0,0, 0,0.01,0);`

(In the latter case, a blank screen occurs.)

Does gluLookAt have a minimum/maximum floating point argument size?

Drawing is done about the origin, within a radius of ~10-6.

Comment: Well now your camera position will be different. That might affect what you can see.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned, the drawing is all done about the origin and within the 10^-6 scale,

Answer (score 0):

Check your value of gluPerspective's minimum draw distance:

`gluPerspective(45.0, (double)window.GetWidth() / (double)window.GetHeight(), 0.1d, 2000.0d);`

This will not work because everything is in-front of 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

`gluLookAt` should work fine with your arguments. However, you are changing the camera position (as @sftrabbit says). Your new position might be too close to the object to see it.

You should check what is the near-plane distance in your perspective matrix setup (possibly your `gluPerspective()` call?).

Comment: That was exactly the problem. (See my answer below.)